# Jquery Tokeninput & Acts-as-taggable is not working with a parent-child-child nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, acts-as-taggable-on

I have form which is built like this:

```
<%= form_for @location do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :product_dates do |d| %>
<%= d.fields_for :products |p| %>
<%= p.text_field :tag_list,"data-pre" => @product.tags.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
```

Now when i go to the page i get an error when using the line: `"data-pre" => @product.tags.map(&:attributes).to_json`  which is `undefined method tags for nil:NilClass` but everything is fine when i take it away. This some type of TokenInput bug? Anyone else had to deal with this?

ProductsController:

```
def new
    @location = Location.new
    product_date = @location.product_dates.build
    product_date.products.build
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply didn't set your `@product` variable => it's `nil`.

You should show your controller

EDIT:

replace:

```
<%= p.text_field :tag_list,"data-pre" => @product.tags.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
```

with:

```
<%= p.text_field :tag_list,"data-pre" => p.object.tags.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
```

This should work for `edit` as well.

It's really good sense here: you can't invoke something you didn't set.

Comment: OK, i updated my question with the Controller. Before when i had just the association of Location and Products (no product date model) to make the nested form it worked.

Comment: Interesting, it started working when i did what you said; i put @product = Product.new inside of the new action. Thanks.